# experimentally virtualising cpu above 64 bits

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Would it not be possible to have a cpu virtualised to more bits than the standard architecture?

If I am not mistaking, it would come down to how much hex code gets processed at one time...

Seems an interesting experimental subject for VirtualBox perhaps.

Maybe, then there would be an ubuntu ( exagerating ) xXbits running, for example...

Comment: They probably have it in there ( or out there ) somewhere... but we don't..*uprising* even I can do it...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about VirtualBox, but Qemu et. al would seem to be a more natural environment for such experiments.

There already is an implementation of [Risc-V 128bit](https://github.com/sysprog21/riscv-emu)